# absolute path to directory in the internal storage in android?

Tags: android, directory, internal-storage

I want to keep my app required files inside a directory under internal storage. in the previous stage i used externalStorageDirectory to store my data. 
 now i am using the below code to refer my external directory

```
 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/mydirectory";
```

I need an equivalant code to refer my directory in the internal directory, can anybody help me...thanks,

**Solution:**

```
getFilesDir()+"/mydirectory";
```

thanks for all of your suggestion and help.

Comment: go through  android docs [http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `getFilesDir()` for that.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir()):

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where
> files created with openFileOutput(String, int) are stored.
>
> No permissions are required to read or write to the returned path,
> since this path is internal storage.

To answer your comment, I'll quote the docs [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal):

> By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your
> application and other applications cannot access them (and the user only can access as root). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are
> removed.

Comment: thankyou, @user3249477 it is the best choice for me. it makes my file more protected right?

Comment: let me know one more thing, i got the absolute path as :" /data/data/packagename/files " will it be changed for other devices?

Comment: @user3737266 yes it can be different on other devices. Never hard-code it as in always use `getFilesDir`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public  File createDir() {
         FIle DIR=null;
         if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
                DIR=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+DIRNAME);
            else
                DIR=context.getCacheDir();
            if(!DIR.exists())
                DIR.mkdirs();
            return DIR;  
    }
```

This one i m using in one of my application and which creates the directory in external if it is mounted or not exists it will create in internal storage

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), "subdir");
```

Comment: can you tell me how the result will be look like, if I am using the below code.
    Log.d("reaching", ":directory"+Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"mydirectory");